# Get the sibling element of a WebElement without XPath [Python/Selenium]

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, siblings

If I'm locating an element using any of the [find](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html) options, what is the best way to get the sibling element of the element I've located?

In my specific scenario, I'm using `find_elements_by_xpath` to get a specific list of elements. I'm then wanting to iterate through those elements, but I need to be able to access the sibling of each item found using the `find_elements_by_xpath` method.

I essentially am looking for this type of functionality:

```
elements = diver.find_elements_by_xpath("//path//to//elements")
for element in elements:
    sibling = element.find_element_by_css_selector(" + .sibling")
```

---

If I'm overthinking this and there is a better approach, I'm all ears.

Comment: Why locating the sibling should be without `xpath`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the javascript to get the sibling element of any element that you have already found.

```
elements = diver.find_elements_by_xpath("//path//to//elements")
for element in elements:
    sibling = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].nextElementSibling", element)
```

In your case, this should work.